# Check if user is offline and update field in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mariadb

I have a field in a table in my database which gets updated whenever a user clicks the logout button. The problem I have is how to update the field when the session is not active and the user did not click the logout button.

I thought at first to check if the user closes the browser, but I am not so sure about this.

Another idea I had is that, after a certain amount of time of inactivity, it updates the field in the database, but I don't know how to do this.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Presumably your server has a hook that you can tie into to get notified when it is ending a session?

Comment: I am using localhost now and the page wlll be using Windows server whenever it is ready

Comment: Are you not using a server locally? How else are you running the PHP code?

Comment: Of course I am. I use xammp

Comment: How can I do what you're saying?

Comment: Store the session data somewhere on your server. Every so often, check for sessions that are expired, and then do whatever it is you need to do.

Comment: Its better to use a simple websocket for this, then you know in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your question with considering some use case. See the user being offline means- >

- 1.Either user click on Logout.
- 2.Or user closes tab or brauser.
- 3.Session expire (if active for long time and doing nothing).

> These are the possible cases. The best solution I can suggest you make
>   one more field in your Database named `last_activity` which may
>   include what user do last time, save it with time.Update your Database
>   while checking this field every particular time i.e. Call a function
>   on a time interval and update your Database accordingly.

`$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE User SET last_action=NOW() WHERE username=?');`

Once you have that, you can list all the users having `last_action > NOW() - [some_duration]`, based on what "online" means on your server (typically, `last_action > NOW() - one hour)`.
You can keep track on everything you want with their online offline status.